# Python 3.4.3: os.system does not run my ping "command"

Tags: python

I made this script to just write the ip or name of the host after clicking on it.... but in python 3.4.3 the code simply do not run the ping; I can input the ip, but it do not run the ping....

I've tried to enter both ways. ex.: "127.0.0.1" or 127.0.0.1

it run in python 2.7, but want it working in a more recent version of python...

My Windows is 7 64 bits

What do you recommend / advise to me?

```
import os
a = input("put the name / ip of the machine you want to ping:\n\n")
p = "ping -t "
os.system(p+a)
```

Should I just simply use python 2.7, which runs well it???

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you are executing the correct code? If anything, it makes more sense that this code won't work on 2.7 and will work on 3 because the different way `input` works.

Comment: What do you enter exactly at the prompt? "127.0.0.1" between double quotes? '127.0.0.1' between simple quotes? If you are on windows + using simple quotes that's normal it does not work. And I cannot figure the "ask again" part from your example. Is it all you are really running?

Comment: which operating system you are in ?

Answer (score 1):

`input` is different between python 2.7 and python 3.

In python 2 it evaluates the return, I bet you enter your string between simple quotes.

In python 3, it returns a string (like `raw_input` did)

Just enter your value without quotes and it will work.

Comment: That's a good catch, but `ping -t "127.0.0.1"` works as well.

Comment: But I'm not sure it solves the question, particularly the "and ask again the host/ip". Well I did not see the MVCE, though...

Comment: `ping -t '127.0.0.1'` doesn't on windows.

Comment: @cavernoso: not good enough: you need to answer the other questions see my previous comments on your question.

Answer (score 1):

## Popen solution:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['ping', '-c 1', 'www.google.com'], stdout=PIPE)
while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    print(line)
```

## sh.ping solution:

```
import sh
for line in sh.ping('www.google.com', '-c 1', _err_to_out=True, _iter=True, _out_bufsize=100):
    print(line)
```

## os.system solution:

```
import os
os.system('ping -c 1 www.google.com')
```

If `os.system()` generates any output, it will be sent to the interpreter standard output stream.

I use the option `-c` to send just one packet.
To construct a command string you can use this approach:

```
a = input("put the name / ip of the machine you want to ping:\n\n")
cmd = 'ping -c 1 %s' % a
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: but I need to input the host / ip when I run the script

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I give up to try it.....
I will use in python 2.7, which runs it well....

Thanks